# sorting a data-table before adding into dataset

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I have a dataset that i need to add into a dataset. I need to sort datatable before adding it into dataset.I can use DataView to sort the datatable but cannot figure out how to add this dataview into the dataset. Any ideas

```
DataView myDataView = MyDataTable.DefaultView;
myDataView.Sort = " Key1, Key2"
MyDataSet.Tables.Add(myDataView);   // no overload that takes a dataview
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `DataTable` by calling [DataView.ToTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw1b4t59.aspx).